# Telerik RadCompression issue - page lost viewstate after a period of time

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, timeout, viewstate

I am experiencing an issue with RadCompression. It does improve my intranet web application performance however I just found an issue, a web page will lose its viewstate if we leave it for around 10 minutes. It has never happened before we use RadCompression since we never let our session timeout. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `sessionstatecompression` or `hiddenfieldcompresion`?

If you are using session, it may not work properly after few postback because you have to increase history size in the web.config `sessionpagestate`.

Comment: This problem was solved some time ago, I remembered that we did increase history size of something in web.config to solve it.